# How to send data from index.html to views.py in django

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I have a table contains a list of fifty companies(items) on a side there is a button. I want to send the name of the company from the table in which user is clicked.

Code of `index.html` :

```
<table class="table table-striped table-dark" cellspacing="0">
   <thead class="bg-info">
      <tr>
         <th>Company's Symbol</th>
         <th>Current Price</th>
         <th>View Current chart</th>
         <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      {% for a,b in stocks %}
      <tr>
         <th scope="row" class="comp_name">{{ a }}</th>
         <td>{{ b }}</td>
         <td>
            <input type="submit" class="btn graph-btn" name="_graph" value="View Graph">
         </td>
         <td>
            <input type="submit" class="btn predict-btn" name="_predict" value="Predict Closing Price">
         </td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
</table>
```

There are two buttons for different URL. Like when user liked on `.graph-btn` it will go to a different URL.

Help.

Comment: What do you mean go to different url. Do you want the user to redirect to different pages based on which button is clicked in a row? If you want the user to redirect, you can use an `<a>` tag and style it like a button. If the data is coming from a database, the `href` should be easily constructable by django url helpers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go to another path (Route) that needs variables

in your template you can use the url function as shown below :

```html
<a href="{% url 'route_name' var %}">.....</a>
```

if you want to get the same result from your python code user reverse method

```py
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('url_path', args(var1)))
```

for more check django's documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/)